# Browser encoding does not match charset setting in meta

Tags: jsp, encoding, character-encoding, weblogic

I have a JSP hosted in Weblogic server.
It will retreive data from database including some Chinese Characters.

Below is the meta in the jsp.

meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Big5"

However, when I open the page by IE, the encoding is Western European and doesn't match the meta setting.

I try the use "view source" and check the content return, the data is correct and the meta encoding is Big5 as expected.

Then, I save the source to local as html and open it again using IE, the encoding become Big5 as expected.

Is the Weblogic server setting cause the problem ?
Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your web app has the following set in the weblogic.xml:

```
<charset-params> 
   <input-charset> 
     <resource-path>/*</resource-path> 
     <java-charset-name>UTF-8</java-charset-name> 
   </input-charset> 
</charset-params>
```

You may also need to play with `<input-charset>` for GET and POST info or map BIG5 to Big5 with `<charset-mapping>`.

See the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13712/weblogic_xml.htm#i1062821).

A very similar question was also asked [Chinese UTF-8 characters are appearing incorrectly in Weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280798/chinese-utf-8-characters-are-appearing-incorrectly-in-weblogic-10-3-but-not-tomc)

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help.

However, I need to set the charset dynamically inside the program, so I cannot hardcode the charset in weblogic.

I found following information from internet.
[link](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html#whyutf8)

In "Embedded encoding disagrees" session, they seems suggest that there is a server setting to override the meta setting, but I don't know where it is set in weblogic.

FYI, I am doing server migration.
In old server, everything work fine but in new one I got this problem. 

The source, weblogic.xml, web.xml are the same as the old server

Comment: Maybe some of the examples here will help: http://tagunov.tripod.com/i18n/i18n.html